# symfony form submission doesn't convert Request array into Entity

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to create a complex form with an embed form in it.

The form needs to create/modify 2 entities at the same time : `Instrument` and `Specification`.

**Some important information before explaining the form problem :**

There is no doctrine relation between this two entities because the `Specification` is not always the same class. For example, if the `Instrument` is a guitar, the class is `GuitarSpecification`, if the instrument is a recorder, the class is `RecorderSpecification`.

Doctrine can not handle this type of relation, so I manage it manually :

- The `Instrument` entity as a property `specification` with associated getter/setter
- `Specification` entity is loaded, persisted, removed in the same time as the `Instrument` through Doctrine Events.

The root form for Instrument is (light version) :

```
class InstrumentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setRequestHandler(new JsonApiRequestHandler());

        $builder
            ->add('name',           TextType::class)
            // ... other fields
        ;

        // Add specification
        $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, \InstrumentBundle\Entity\InstrumentType $instrumentType = null) {
            $prefix = null === $instrumentType ? 'Abstract' : $instrumentType->getPrefix();

            $form->add('specification', 'InstrumentBundle\\Form\\Specification\\' . $prefix . 'SpecificationType');
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // Get Instrument Entity
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getInstrumentType());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('instrumentType')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // Get Instrument Entity
                $instrumentType = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $instrumentType);
            }
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'data_class'      => 'InstrumentBundle\Entity\Instrument'
        ]);
    }
}
```

The lonely complexity of this form is there are event listeners (`PRE_SET_DATA` and `POST_SUBMIT`) which check the type of the `Instrument` (guitar, recorder, etc.) and add the correct `Specification` form (GuitarSpecification, RecorderSpecification, etc.).

Here is an example of one of my `Specification` form type :

```
class GuitarSpecificationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('leftHanded',    CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('headstock',     TextType::class)
            ->add('body',          TextType::class)
            ->add('amplification', TextType::class)
            ->add('strings',       IntegerType::class)
            ->add('frets',         IntegerType::class)
            ->add('tuning')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'data_class'      => 'InstrumentBundle\Entity\Specification\GuitarSpecification'
        ]);
    }
}
```

My problem is when the form is submitted, the part of the Request array for the `Specification` is not converted to the Entity, and I obtain an error :

```
Expected argument of type "InstrumentBundle\Entity\Specification\AbstractSpecification", "array" given
```

I can't find a way to resolve this one, so any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just a question, it's not possible to solve your problem of different 'specification' with the inheritance-mapping of Doctrine2 ?

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping

Comment: I could have used the Table Inheritance, but I was worried about the performance impact.

Comment: your line  ' $form->add('specification', 'InstrumentBundle\\Form\\Specification\\' . $prefix . 'SpecificationType');  '  should be  " $form->add('specification', EntityType::class, array( 'class'  => 'InstrumentBundle:Specification\' . $prefix . 'SpecificationType'' " no ?

Comment: The EntityType will only permits to select into existing Entities. I want to create / Update a new one with an embedded form.

Comment: for that you have to use prototype and a bit of javascript hers is the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: What you describe is for Collection. The "relation" I have is a One-to-One.